# Is there a way to find out the creator of a share in Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2003, share

A new share has been created on a server I use and we need to find out who created it and when. Is there a way to find that out? It's Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Comment: view the details of the directory listing in explorer and modify the view to include the owner, there is no creator attribute, maybe you can get more information if there are any files in the share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way to get who and when the share was created is if you have enabled auditing policy for local file or folder on the server.

if the auditing was enabled you can see the information you are searching for in the Event Viewer under security logs.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have auditing enabled your best bet is the *owner* of that folder. By default the creator of a folder is also the owner. It is not 100% reliable because ownership can be taken away.

- Right-click the folder - click Properties.
- Security tab
- Click Advanced, and then click the Owner tab.

Comment: This answer is worth my job Reputation! One of my client created a extra folder and moved all other files there which was causing problems in my application. Initially they accused me for this but then I found who created the folder :D